# How to compress GIF image before uploading to server in android?

Tags: android, compression, gif

how to compress GIF image before upload it to the server ?, i tried some android libraries to compress gif image but it convert it to png image. is there any way to compress gif image ?

Comment: GIF is a compressed file format. GIF images are already compressed.

Comment: @CommonsWare i know but the gif image size is too big, and it's not a good practice to upload big size image to the server, i'm trying to reduce the size

Comment: That would be reducing the image's resolution, then, not compression.

Answer (score 0):

im using a bitmap in my projects.

[Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap)

Example code:

```
 ImageView carView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagen_cr7);

                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(picture, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                        InputStream input=new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
                        Bitmap ext_pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                        carView.setImageBitmap(ext_pic);
```

Comment: can you provide an example of your solution ti make it more clear ?

Comment: byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(person_object.getPhoto(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
InputStream inputStream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
user_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Answer (score 0):

GIF is a *lossless* image compression format: it is set up to reproduce the image exactly.
 As a consequence, there is no "image quality" slider (as in JPEG encoders); although a GIF will likely be much smaller than an uncompressed format (such as many camera RAW or common TIFF options), there is a limit to how far it can go.

Also, you should know that GIF is limited to 8 bits per pixel (so it is most appropriate for line art, not photo-like images).  If your source image is a full 24 bits, it must be dithered to fit into a 256-entry color palette.  So, although the GIF format itself is lossless, the image processing required to use it in the first place may be lossy.

There are a number of things you can do to reduce the size of your image file:

- You can choose a lossy format (such as JPEG), which will allow much greater compression.  Note that JPEG works well on photo-like images, but not so well on line art.  Also, (although your question explicitly rejects it) PNG may be a reasonable option, as it (losslessly) supports 24-bpp images.
- As mentioned in a comment, you can try reducing the resolution of your image, and shipping the reduced version.  If you can't generate a smaller image to start with, image resizing typically works well on photo-like images, and there are nonlinear resizing filters available that are specifically intended to handle line art.
- If a full-resolution GIF is mandatory for your application, you may be able to generate an image that is more compressible by the GIF format.  GIF compresses solid blocks of color extremely well -- but does less well on dithered or noisy images (such as you might get from converting a 24-bpp image to GIF format).

Since you have not given any information on your requirements (what kind of image you have, where you got it, and what you need it for), it is hard to come up with specific advice.

However, there is a good chance that your GIF has far more resolution than you need for your particular application (leading to option #2).